# How to use filter in Python with a function which belongs to an object which is an element on the list being filtered?

Tags: python, filter

To be specific in my case, the **class Job** has a number of **Task** objects on which it operates.

```
 import tasker 

 class Job(object): 
    _name = None 
    _tasks = []
    _result = None 

    def __init__(self, Name): 
        self._name = Name

    def ReadTasks(self): 
        # read from a Json file and create a list of task objects. 

    def GetNumTasks(self):
        return len(self._tasks)

    def GetNumFailedTasks(self):
        failTaskCnt = 0
        for task in self._tasks:
            if task.IsTaskFail():
                failTaskCnt += 1
```

To make **GetNumFailedTasks** more succinct, I would like to use a filter, but I am not sure what is the correct way to provide filter with IsTaskFail as the first parameter.

In case, this is a duplicate, please mark it so, and point to the right answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a generator expression with `sum`:

```
failTaskCnt = sum(1 for task in self._tasks if task.IsTaskFail())
```

Comment: Thats a good alternate. So perhaps better not to use filter in this case?

Comment: @vivekian2: With `filter` you'd iterate twice over the same elements. Seems wasteful.

Comment: On a side note, code like this can also be written as `sum(task.IsTaskFail() for task in self._tasks)` if the expression will always yield a boolean. Using bools as the numbers they basically are isn't particular widespread though, some may be caught off guard by it.